# Unable to run RC commands under Selenium Grid 2

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, remote-control

I've tried this on multiple versions of selenium 2 (from 2.24-2.28) and on two different systems. It's a very simple scenario. I want to run RC commands via Selenium Grid and I don't want to port my 1000+ test scripts to WebDriver, so hopefully that's not the only solution.

Test case:

1) START HUB:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar -role hub
```

2) START NODE:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```

(I've tried every variation of this I could think of, including -role rc)

Communications seem fine between the two. The console status is up and shows the connection between the two.

3) REQUEST RC URL:

```
http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=getNewBrowserSession&1=*firefox&2=http://www.google.com
```

Output is always:

HTTP ERROR: 500

Problem accessing /selenium-server/driver/. Reason:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

If I revert to non-grid mode, the request returns as expected.

Am I missing something or is RC simply not supported under Grid 2?

Comment: I filed a bug with the Selenium team on this. A fix was released today. The issue will be solved with v2.30

[link]http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5113[/link]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be fixed for *firefox as a browser in 2.30 however I still observe the same behaviour for *googlechrome